# How to delete some old files and keep the latest three copies only?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I want to delete some old files and keep the latest 3 copies with powershell command.

such as :

```
A.1.0.txt
A.3.0.txt
A.6.1.txt
A.9.2.txt
A.2.2.txt
B.1.txt
B.4.txt
B.7.4.txt
B.0.3.2.6.4.txt
....
```

Each file has the timestamp.
It seems easy handle by bash shell,such as :

```
ls -t A.*txt| head -n -3 | xargs --no-run-if-empty rm
ls -t B.*txt| head -n -3 | xargs --no-run-if-empty rm
```

I am not good at powershell all command,is there any way to delete the old files?
Could some one give me some advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to delete **all** files in the directory *except* the 3 newest files, these would be the commands:

```
$Items = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Path\to\files\" -File
$Items | Sort-Object CreationTime | Select-Object -First ($Item.Count - 3) | Remove-Item
```

Comment: Be careful here, because Get-ChildItem **without** parameter `-File` will also return subdirectories and I don't think you want to remove these too. Also, I would recommend using property `LastWriteTime` instead of `CreationTime` as the latter changes when a file is copied from elsewhere, while `LastWriteTime` holds the last modified time

Comment: @Theo good point. I added the `-File` parameter

Answer (score 0):

```
$Items = Get-ChildItem -Path ./A.[0-9]*
$Items | Sort-Object CreationTime  |Select-Object -first ($Items.count -3)
```

or

```
$Items = Get-ChildItem -Path ./A.[0-9]*
$Items | Sort-Object LastWriteTime |Select-Object -first ($Items.count -3)
```